# Leaflet error: h.fn is undefined when using layer.on('loading') event

Tags: javascript, leaflet, esri-leaflet, dynamic-layer

In my Leaflet application (version <strike>1.0.1</strike> **1.0.3**) I connect to ArcGIS Server via the Esri Leaflet plugin. I load the layer as dynamic layer:

```
var layerUrl = "http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services//service1/MapServer";
var layer1 = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({ 
   url: layerUrl, 
});
```

I only load this layer when a checkbox is clicked:

```
if (checkBox.checked){
    map.addLayer(layer);
}
```

Now my goal is, to show the cursor as 'wait' during the layer is loading. So I add this line:

```
layer.on('loading' , cursorWait());
```

The cursorWait function is this:

```
function cursorWait() {
    document.body.className = 'wait';
}
```

CSS:

```
.wait, .wait * { cursor: wait; }
```

Which works great, but now I get error messages on my console:

```
TypeError: h.fn is undefined  leaflet.js:5:4965
    fire                     file:///C:/folder1/Leaflet/LeafletLib/Leaflet/leaflet.js:5:4965
    _renderImage             https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri/2.0.0-beta.7/esri-leaflet.js:5:10474
    _requestExport/<         https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri/2.0.0-beta.7/esri-leaflet.js:5:17673
    _createServiceCallback/< https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri/2.0.0-beta.7/esri-leaflet.js:4:24163
    bound                    self-hosted:916:17
    createRequest/httpRequest.onreadystatechange https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/leaflet.esri/2.0.0-beta.7/esri-leaflet.js:4:9620
```

My question is: does someone know why these error messages occur?
What really bugs me, that they appear only if I add the `layer.on('loading',..)` line, but then it appears also when I zoom in or out, although I am calling this only when the checkbox is checked. Also it seems to print an error message for each tile (?).
Am I using the `layer.on('loading',..)` event wrong? Or is it a bug? Should I just ignore the error messages?

Comment: Please specify your Leaflet version. Also, be aware that using `leaflet-src.js` instead of `leaflet.js` will give you better debug info.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the post, I am currently using version 1.0.1. I will try leaflet-src.js and also maybe a newer leaflet version.

Comment: I have updated to version 1.0.3 and using leaflet-src now. The error is the same and I don't see more debug info :(. Where is it supposed to be? I am using firefox developer tools

Comment: No, the error can not be the same. You cannot see `h.fn` using `leaflet-src.js`.

Comment: Yes you are right. Now it is l.fn... but it does not give me more debug info :(

Comment: Can you please update your question with the exact error message and new line numbers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61098/discussion-between-ylka-and-ivansanchez).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can (and should) skip including the parentheses when you wire up your event listener to a named function.

```
layer.on('loading' , cursorWait); // not cursorWait()
```

> it appears also when I zoom in or out, although I am calling this only when the checkbox is checked.

the 'loading' event is fired each and every time a new image is requested from the map service.  this happens each time the map is panned/zoomed.
 ([reference](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/blob/0da3cf7e17bcd4ef1abd3970bac221b3881eb86a/src/Layers/RasterLayer.js#L227-L229))

unrelated tangent: we have released 10 patches for esri-leaflet since 2.0.0-beta.7, any reason you aren't upgrading?

Comment: Thanks, leaving out the parenthesis did the trick, now I don't see any error messages. But the problem is now it is not wokring as expected, beacause the wait cursor appears only immediately before the layer is shown. (Like for a ms, sometimes you don't even see it.) 
About the version: IvanSanchez pointed out that I am using an outdated version of esri-leaflet and upgraded since then to 2.0.8.

Comment: yup. 'loading' is not the most appropriate event for you to listen for if you'd like to show a loading indicator for the duration of time between when the layer is first checked on and an image is painted for the first time.

Comment: so which event would you suggest?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Thanks @John Gravois. Now I am calling the cursorWait() function immediately after the checkbox was checked, without listening to a layer event. I was apparently overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this solution in case someone is trying to implement something similar like a loading indicator:

```
if (checkBox.checked){
    map.addLayer(layer);
    cursorWait();
    layer.on('load', function(){document.body.classList.remove("wait");});
}

function cursorWait() {
    document.body.className = 'wait';
}
```

The problem was that I was trying to listen to the loading event which in this case makes not much sense, I can just call the 'wait' cursor when the checkbox is checked.
Thanks to John Gravois for pointing me in the right direction